# Optimize code to compute the improper Euler integral

Tags: c++, algorithm

How can I optimize the following code?

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "UtilitiesP.h"
#include "Simpson.h"

int main(void)
{
    double agm(1/functionsP::agm(1, 2));
    double integral( (2/constantsP::kPi) * Simpson(0, constantsP::kPi*0.5, constantsP::kEps, functionsP::eliptic));
    assert(fabs(agm-integral)<constantsP::kEps);

    double firstVal(constantsP::kPi*0.5);
    integral = Simpson(constantsP::kAlmostZero, 10000, constantsP::kEps, functionsP::Dirichlet);

    std::cout << firstVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << integral << std::endl;

    double secondVal(sqrt(constantsP::kPi)*0.5);
    integral = Simpson(constantsP::kAlmostZero, 12, constantsP::kEps, functionsP::Puasson);

    std::cout << secondVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << integral << std::endl;

    double thirdVal(constantsP::kPi/sin(constantsP::kNumberFromEuler*constantsP::kPi));
    integral = Simpson(constantsP::kAlmostZero, 13, constantsP::kEps, functionsP::Euler);

    std::cout << thirdVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << integral << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**Utilities.h**

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

//#define NDEBUG
#include <cassert>

namespace constantsP
{
    const double kPi(3.1415926535897932);
    const double kEps(1.e-12);
    const double kAlmostZero(1.e-7);
    const double kBigNumber(30);
    const double kNumberFromEuler(0.4);
};

namespace functionsP
{
    double agm(const double&, const double&);
    double eliptic(const double&);
    double Dirichlet(const double&);
    double Puasson(const double&);
    double Euler(const double&);
};
```

**Utilities.cpp**

```
#include "UtilitiesP.h"

double functionsP::agm(const double& a, const double& b)
{
    if(a <= 0 || b <= 0)
    {throw std::invalid_argument("Arithmetic-geometric mean is defined only for 0 < a < b.");}

    double aPrev(a), bPrev(b), aCurrent(a), bCurrent(b);
    do
    {
        aPrev = aCurrent;
        bPrev = bCurrent;
        aCurrent = sqrt(aPrev*bPrev);
        bCurrent = (aPrev+bPrev)*0.5;
    }while((aPrev < aCurrent) && (bCurrent < bPrev) && (aPrev < bPrev));

    double res((aPrev <= aCurrent)?aPrev:bPrev);

    return res;
}

double functionsP::eliptic(const double& x)
{
    return 1/sqrt(pow(1*sin(x), 2) + pow(2*cos(x), 2));
}

double functionsP::Dirichlet(const double& x)
{
    return sin(2*x)/x;
}

double functionsP::Puasson(const double& x)
{
    return exp(-(x*x));
}

double functionsP::Euler(const double& x)
{
    return pow(x, constantsP::kNumberFromEuler-1)/(1+x);
}
```

**Simpson.h**

```
#include <cmath>

double Simpson (const double& a, const double& b, const double& eps, double(*const f)(const double&));
```

**Simpson.cpp**

```
#include "Simpson.h"

double Simpson (const double& a, const double& b, const double& eps, double(*const f)(const double&))
{
    double step((b-a)*0.5);
    double s1(step*(f(a)+f(b))), s2(0), s4(4*step*f(a+step));
    double previousSum(0), currentSum(s1+s4);
    int n(2);
    do 
    {
        previousSum = currentSum;
        n += n;
        step *= 0.5;

        s1 *= 0.5;
        s2 = 0.5*s2+0.25*s4;

        s4 = 0;
        for(int i(1); i < n; i+=2)
        {s4 += f(a+i*step);}
        s4 = 4*step*s4;

        currentSum = s1+s2+s4;
    }
    while(eps<fabs(previousSum-currentSum));

    return currentSum/3;
}
```

After running the code you will see that it works well for the first two integral. But it works very bad for the last one. It takes very much time to compute it. What can I change in order to make it work faster? What comments about the style do you have?

Comment: If you have working code this question better fits for [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For Stack Overflow that's probably _too broad_.

Comment: Disagree. Codereview.se isn't good at this sort of numerical code. But numerical code optimization is an art of its own. Stack overflow isn't much better.

Comment: My guess is that you have an denormal number in one of the doubles.

Comment: @Surt, never heard about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) thank you for the information. But it is still not enough to solve my issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the code. The algorithm just doesn't converge well on such a steep function. Consider the [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Error) of approximating the integral on the interval `[kAlmostZero, kAlmostZero+step]`.The 4-th derivative of `Euler()` at `kAlmostZero` is ~10^33. Which means, in order to make the error less than 10^-12, the step needs to be ~10^-8, and the number of steps will be ~10^9. And this only accounts for the error contributed by the very first step.

Comment: As an illustration, [this](https://pastebin.com/7rh5d27c) will calculate the last integral much faster.